# Working with iphone camera

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I am using UIPickerView controller for displaying the camera on iphone screen for click event of button.
I want to add one button Draw Line on the camera screen and also i want to add an event with that Draw Line Button means if i will click on Draw Line button a one line will be draw on the screen of  camera.
So pls reply me is it possible? and if yes then pls give me your reply with some examples or links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be possible. You can achieve this with `cameraOverlayView` in [UIImagePickerController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIImagePickerController).

Comment: sorry dude,I refered that link whatever  you have provided on above line but i didn't understand can you provide me any example related to   my problem its argent!!!!!

Comment: Contruct a new UIView object with the button and other things u wanted. Set that view to the cameraOverlayView.